# Convert list of two dimensional DataFrame to Torch Tensor

Tags: python, dataframe, pytorch, torch

**Goal:** I am working with RNNs in PyTorch, and my data is given by a list of DataFrames, where each DataFrame means one observation like:

```
import numpy as np
data = [pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,50))) for x in range(100)]
```

which means 100 observation, with 50 parameters and 5 timesteps each. For my Model i need a tensor of shape `(100,5,50)`.

**Issue:** I tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work, does anyone know how this is done?
This approaches doesn't work:

```
import torch
torch.tensor(np.array(data))
```

I thing the problem is to convert the DataFrames into Arrays and the List into a Tensor at the same time.

Comment: hey, I'm interested in how you model your problem, do you mind share the knowledge? Or any reference/tutorial I can look for? As most of the tutorials are on 2D matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can convert the list of dataframes in a single command, but you can convert the list of dataframes into a list of tensors and then concatenate the list.

E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch

data = [pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,50))) for x in range(100)]

list_of_arrays = [np.array(df) for df in data]
torch.tensor(np.stack(list_of_arrays))

#or

list_of_tensors = [torch.tensor(np.array(df)) for df in data]
torch.stack(list_of_tensors)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's too late, but if someonelse is still asking this question somewhere... This is for you <3

```
import torch
import numpy as np
list_of_dataframe : List[pd.DataFrame] #= ....
my_tensor = torch.tensor(np.array(list_of_dataframe))
```

(python 3.9, numpy 1.20, pytorch 1.10)